# Why do we have $u_n=\bigl(\frac{n}{n+1}\bigr)^{n^2}=\exp(-n+o(n) )$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Why do we have

$u_n=\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2}=\exp\left(-n+o\left(n\right) \right)$

My attempts :

- $\ln\left(1+\dfrac 1n\right)=\dfrac 1n-\dfrac1{2n^2}+o\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)$ but I got  $-n^2\ln\left(1+\dfrac 1n\right)=-n+\dfrac 12+o(1)$

  -

Comment: Do you mean to write $u_n=(n/(n+1))^{\color{red}{n^2}}$?

Comment: You do realize that $\dfrac{1}{2}+o(1) = o(n)$, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You just need to show that $1/2 + o(1) = o(n)$. Since $o(1) \to 0$, $o(1)/n \to 0$. So $$\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2} + o(1)\right) = \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{o(1)}{n} \to 0.$$ This shows that $1/2 + o(1) = o(n)$.